# Issue viewing source files in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I'm using Doxyfile 1.8.17, and decompiling an Android app, with apktool, and also unzipping the APK to view some files in there too with Doxygen. I've managed to pull only what I need using EXCLUDE_PATHS. SOURCE_BROWSER is set to YES. My problem is whenever I go to click on the file in File List, I just get a link to go to the source code of the file. When I click it, it opens the source code in the right plane. I would like to just click the left plane and view the source code instantly in the right plane, however, there doesn't seem to be an option to change the behaviour. In the html output folder there is two types of files. `foo.html` and `foo_source.html`. This is the same for every file that you pull from INPUT sources. I just want it to show me `foo_source.html` and nothing else. Is this possible?

Comment: No this is not possible. Doxygen is a documentation browser and as a possibility one can go from the documentation to the source (or even display the source inside the documentation).

Comment: iNalyzer from AppSec does this very thing. You click on the file on the left plane, and the contents are viewable instantly on the right plane, without needing to click "Go to source code of this file" - I just wanted to make my own for Android, and while I have, this little part is annoying, to have to click a URL through to view source, on every file.